# Can't get model variable at the jspx page

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, jspx

I working with spring 3.1 and method should return a view that represented by jspx page. While in debug i see variable in model named `noteList`, i can't print or iterate this variable on the page.

The output is `${noteList}`.

Here is some code:

```
@RequestMapping( value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView rootPage(){
    List<Note> result = sessionFactory.openSession().createCriteria(Note.class).list();

    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("index");
    mv.addObject(result);
    return mv;
}
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<jsp:root xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/tags" version="2.0">
    <jsp:directive.page language="java"
        contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" />

    <![CDATA[<!DOCTYPE html>]]>
    <html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Index page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <c:out value="${noteList}"/> 
</body>
    </html>
</jsp:root>
```

---

```
<beans:bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jspx" />
    </beans:bean>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks all! i have got an answer.

The problem was in the jspx page

working page contains next code at the beginning:

```
 <jsp:root xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/tags"
    xmlns:form="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" version="2.0">

    <jsp:output doctype-root-element="html" omit-xml-declaration="true"
        doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        doctype-system="http://www.w3c.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd" />
    <jsp:directive.page language="java"
        contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" />

    <html>
<head>
.....
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the `noteList` contains list of object type `Note`, you can try accessing one of the attributes of the `Note` object. Suppose you have a `name` attribute in `Note`, then try `{node.name}` in your jsp.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ModelAndView addObject(String attributeName, Object attributeValue)](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/ModelAndView.html#addObject%28java.lang.Object%29) instead.

E.g.:

```
mv.addObject("noteList", result);
```

Then in JSPX

```
<c:forEach items="${noteList}" var="node">
  ${node}
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: This way doesn't help too.
Page shows only "${node}". And there is only one object in the list.